# How do you derive this easy to find the max/min points

Tags: derivatives

How do you derive this easy to find the max/min points (There aren't actually any stationary points)

$$ \dfrac {-24 x^2 -88 x -18}  {16 x^2 +64 x +16} $$

I know how to use the quotient rule, but I think this has to be simplified at first, else it would be an extremely long approach.

Many thanks!

Comment: * derivate $\to$ differentiate

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as $-\frac32+\frac{4x+3}{8x^2+32x+8}$, then use the quotient rule.
For the derivative of $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ to be zero, you need 
$$\frac{p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)}{q(x)^2}=0\\p'(x)q(x)=p(x)q'(x)$$
so you don't need to write down the denominator.

Comment: But you should confirm that the denominator is not zero at that point as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a common factor between the numerator and denominator, which there isn't here, there isn't much you can do.  Just plug ahead with the quotient rule.

Comment: constant factors of numerator and denominator also do not enter into picture here.

Answer (score 0):

By Quotient Rule
$$ \dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)} = \dfrac{p^{'}(x)}{q^{'}(x)} $$

It is so convenient to put numerator, denominator into four compartments raster with = sign in between.

Remove common factors from numerator and denominator at the first opportunity to reduce needless calculation with bigger numbers later.

$$ \dfrac{-12 x^2 -44 x -9}{(x^2 + 4 x + 4)} = \dfrac{-24 x -44 }{2 x + 4}= \dfrac{-12 x -22 }{ x + 2 }  $$  (was in typo error)

Now easier to cross multiply, collect terms and consolidate into a quadratic equation.

EDIT:

after correction:

$$ \dfrac{12 x^2 + 44 x + 9}{(x^2 + 4 x + 1)} = \dfrac{24 x + 44 }{2 x + 4}= \dfrac{12 x +22 }{ x + 2 }$$

Cross multiplying,

$$ 12 x^3 + 68 x^2 + 97 x + 18  = 12 x^3 + 70 x^2 + 100 x +22, $$

Simplifies to quadratic equation $ 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 = 0 $

Has no real roots as the discriminant = $  9 - 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 < 0  $

Zeroes are $ @ \pm \infty $ with horizontal asymptotes and with no extrema.

Apologies for using this space for comment replies.

@Michael:There is no confusion between any two things. Did the OP talk about difficulties in evaluating an indeterminate quotient at any given $x=x_1$ point or is he asking about finding extremum value of a quotient at an unevaluated  or unknown point $x=x_1 $  yet to be determined? The former calls for L'Hospital's Rule and the latter calls for an application of the Quotient Rule.

If at a known point $ x=x_1, F(x_1) = \dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)} $ takes the form $ 0/0, or, \infty/\infty $, then L’Hospital’s Rule can be applied to evaluate the indeterminate function of x  with one , two or more  separate differentiations of the numerator and denominator depending on the degree of indeterminacy :

$$  \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac {f’(x)}{g’(x)} = \dfrac {f’’(x)}{g’’(x)}   etc. $$

On the other hand to find extremum point ($x=x_1)$ and corresponding ($ y=y_1 $) without reference to c or involving c, we can use Quotient Rule $  F(x) = \dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}= const. = c, then \; each = \dfrac {f’(x)}{g’(x)} @ x=x_1.$ OP wants this only, I replied to this specifically.

There is *similarity about the operation or procedure* (viz., proceeding with individual differentiation of numerator and denominator) in either situation. However, the *objectives of the two  operations are  entirely different*.

As an often quoted example:

$ \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is determinate at all x except at $x=0$. It becomes determined ( as unity) using L'Hospital's Rule.

Next, to find all extremum values $x_1$ of this function just as OP has asked, one solves the equation:

$$ \dfrac{\sin (x_1)} {x_1} = \dfrac {\cos( x_1)}{1}, or , tan(x_1) = x_1. $$

Hope it resolved the confusion.

Comment: This is incorrect.  You have confused the quotient rule with L'Hopital's rule.